# Toiveling Keilim on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tevilas-keilim-dipping

Can you Toivel Keilim on Shabbos?

Comment: ספק חשיכה, ספק לא חשיכה--אין מעשרין את הוודאי, **ואין מטבילין את הכלים**, ואין מדליקין את הנרות; אבל מעשרין את הדמאי, ומערבין, וטומנין את החמין.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tevilas keilim may be done by day or
>   night, except Shabbos or Yom Tov. In
>   case of great necessity, where one
>   needs to use an untoveled keili on
>   Shabbos or Yom Tov, the utensil should
>   be given to a non-Jew as a present and
>   the Yehudi should borrow it back.
>   After Shabbos, if the Yehudi
>   re-purchased the utensil from the
>   non-Jew, it must be toveled with a
>   brocha. If the Yehudi continues to use
>   the keili without paying for it, the
>   keili will require tevila without a
>   brocha. If one is in doubt whether a
>   keili needs tevila, a Rav must be
>   consulted. If one is in doubt if a
>   vessel that requires tevila was
>   toveled, it should now be immersed
>   without a brocha.

http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-tevilas.htm

Answer (score 6):

> Question: All forbid Tevilas Kelim on
>   Shabbos. What is the reason?
>
> Answer #1 (Rabah): This is a decree
>   lest one carry them four Amos in
>   Reshus ha'Rabim.
>
> Answer #2 (Rav Yosef): It is a decree
>   lest one squeeze (water out of
>   clothing).
>
> Question (Abaye): Why is it forbidden
>   to be Tovel Kelim for which this is
>   not a concern (e.g. a knife)?
>
> Answer (Rav Yosef): It is a decree
>   lest one be Tovel other Kelim and
>   squeeze them.

http://dafyomi.co.il/beitzah/halachah/bt-hl-019.htm

> Rambam (Hilchos Shabbos 23:8): One may
>   not be Tovel Tamei Kelim on Shabbos
>   because it looks like Tikun
>   Keli.

http://dafyomi.co.il/beitzah/halachah/bt-hl-019.htm

There are opinions that hold you may - please see link for at length discussion